# If $|\vec {A}.\vec {B}|=|\vec {A} \times \vec {B}|$, then find the resultant of $\vec {A}$ and $\vec {B}$

Tags: vectors

If $|\vec {A}.\vec {B}|=|\vec {A} \times \vec {B}|$, then find the resultant of $\vec {A}$ and $\vec {B}$

My Attempt:
$$|\vec {A}.\vec {B}|=|\vec {A} \times \vec {B}|$$
$$|\vec {A}|.|\vec {B}|.\cos \theta=|\vec {A}|.|\vec {B}|\sin \theta n^{\cap}$$
$$\cos \theta=\sin \theta n^{\cap}$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: You should have made clear that you are trying to find the **magnitude** of the resultant.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ are non-zero:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
|\vec A \cdot \vec B| &=& |\vec A \times \vec B| \\
|\vec A| |\vec B| \cos \theta &=& |\vec A| |\vec B| \sin \theta \\
\cos \theta &=& \sin \theta \\
\theta &=& 45^\circ
\end{array}$$

Therefore, $|\vec A + \vec B|^2 = |\vec A|^2 + |\vec B|^2 - 2|\vec A||\vec B|\cos45^\circ = |\vec A|^2 + |\vec B|^2 - \sqrt2|\vec A||\vec B|$.

Therefore, $|\vec A + \vec B| = \sqrt{|\vec A|^2 + |\vec B|^2 - \sqrt2|\vec A||\vec B|}$.

Comment: Do we not need $n$ for calculation?

Comment: @Ramanujan $\vec A \times \vec B = |\vec A||\vec B| (\sin \theta) \hat n$, where $|\hat n| = 1$. Then take magnitude of both sides.

Comment: and one more thing, How did you get $-$ sign in your answer? The book's answer is $\sqrt {A^2+B^2+\sqrt {2} AB}$.

Comment: @Ramanujan That would be when $\theta = 135^\circ$.

Comment: Why is $|\vec {A}+\vec {B}|^{2}=|\vec {A}|^2+|\vec {B}|^2-2|\vec {A}|.|\vec {B}|.\cos \theta$?

Comment: @ ΘΣΦGenSan, Why is cosine law needed.here?

Comment: @Ramanujan Ignore my comment.

Comment: @Ramanujan either cosine law, or $|\vec A+\vec B|^2 = (\vec A+\vec B) \cdot (\vec A+\vec B) = \vec A \cdot \vec A + \vec B \cdot \vec B + 2\vec A \cdot \vec B = |\vec A|^2 + |\vec B|^2 + 2 |\vec A| |\vec B|\cos\theta$

Comment: @DHMO Just curious. Yes, $\theta=45^\circ$. Should we have $$|\vec A + \vec B|^2 = |\vec A|^2 + |\vec B|^2 - 2|\vec A||\vec B|\cos22.5^\circ$$

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan where does $22.5^\circ$ come from?

Comment: @DHMO Based on the definition of the vector sum graphically?

Comment: @DHMO, @ ΘΣΦGenSan, Isn't the magnitude of resultant given by $R=\sqrt {A^2+B^2+2AB\cos \theta}$

Comment: @DHMO, so what's your elaboration?

Comment: Why the $-1$ downvote??